# Content get hidden in responsive grid bootstrap-vue

Tags: html, css, vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I am developing a vue application using bootstrap-vue.
My template and styles looks like this,

```
<template>
  <div>
    <b-container class="p-0 mt-3" fluid>
      <b-row style="height:110px">
        <b-col cols="4" sm="4" md="4" lg="2" xl="2" style="background-color:white">
          <div style="border-right:solid; border-color:#576367" class="p-2 mt-2">
            <b-row  class="mt-3">
              <p style="font-size:16px;color:#01151C; font-weight:bold;margin: 0px;">{{meeting.meetingTime | moment("MMMM Do") }}</p>
            </b-row>
            <b-row>
              <p style="font-size: 14px;">{{meeting.meetingTime | moment("h:mm a") }}</p>
            </b-row>
          </div>
        </b-col>
        <b-col cols="8" sm="8" md="6" lg="4" xl="3" style="background-color:white" class="p-2">
          <div class="p-2 mt-1">
            <div class="left-align" :style="{backgroundColor: getColor()}" style="width:60px;height:57px;color:white; border-radius: 7px;">
              <p style="position: absolute;top: 15px; left: 17px;">{{getInitials(meeting.partnerName)}}</p>
            </div>
            <p class="left-align ml-2 mt-2" style="font-size:16px;color:#01151C; font-weight:bold; margin:0px">{{meeting.partnerName}}</p>
            <p class="left-align ml-2">
              <b-icon icon="envelope" aria-hidden="true"></b-icon>  {{meeting.partnerEmail}}
            </p>
          </div>
        </b-col>
        <b-col cols="6" sm="6" md="5" lg="2" xl="2" style="background-color:white" class="p-2">
          <p class="ml-2 mt-4 mb-0">{{meeting.meetingParticipants}}</p>
          <p class="ml-2">Participants</p>
        </b-col>
        <b-col cols="6" sm="6" md="5" lg="3" xl="2" style="background-color:white" class="p-2">
          <b-button variant="outline-primary" class="mt-4">Start Meeting</b-button>
        </b-col>
      </b-row>
    </b-container>
  </div>
</template> 
<style scoped>
  .left-align {
    position: relative;
    float: left
  }
</style>
```

for the `xl` and `lg` breakpoints its working fine. [image: in xl breakpoint] But after it reach the `md` break point content start to get hidden by the content above it. [image: in mdbreak point].

Button and the number of participants get hidden. But if I add margin top to the row using chrome dev tools it looks fine. I tried adding media queries, but I found out there are no media query for xs break point. I am very new to responsive development and couldn't found out any resource to solve my problem.

Comment: Please post a workable environment to reproduce your issue in codesandbox

Answer (score 0):

I can see that your `md` is exceeding the count of 12. In responsive design, the screen will be split in to 12 columns. So you have to define elements between the 12 columns.

*For Example*

your 4 `b-col` elements will have `md-3` in each, which adds up to 12.

You have to split your elements within 12 columns to display in the screen. So only you cant see it on the screen.

> P.S. The same applies to other breakpoints.

Answer (score 0):

I have added `<b-row style="height:110px">` height to the row, making the mess